# Poner Cero a la Izquierda automáticamente al poner punto (.) en un textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

como mi pregunta lo dices, ve si podrían ayudarme con mi caso:
quiero conseguir que al seleccionar la tecla punto en un **Textbox** vacío este me ponga el cero a la izquierda y me permita seguir digitando.

1. al escribir                **.22**
2. resultado automático      **0.22**

Comment: que haz intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil de realizar. Necesitas utilizar la acción `TextChanged` del control `Textbox`.
La acción antes mencionada realiza algo cada que se cambia el texto del componente. Teniendo esto en mente, tenemos que comprobar 2 cosas:

1. Que lo que se ingrese en el texbox tenga un punto
2. Si tiene punto, revisar que en el lado izquierdo del punto, no haya nada

¿Cómo comprobamos esto? Sencillo, para el primer punto utilizamos `Contains()` para ver si el texto contiene un punto.

Para el segundo, utilizaremos `split()`, que devuelve un `array` de `strings` por cada vez que "partió" el `string` por cada punto que se encontró. Siguiendo esta lógica, el primer elemento del `array`, es la parte de la izquierda, entonces, sólo hay que verificar que no haya nada en él. Yo lo comprobé verificando que la longitud de ese elemento sea cero o menor.

Finalmente, si la longitud es cero, añadimos el `"0"` al inicio de la cadena del textbox. Espero la respuesta te sea de ayuda. ¡Saludos!

```
//verificamos si tiene punto
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                //separamos por punto
                string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
                //si el primer elemento está vacío, significa que no se escribió nada antes de, entonces, añadimos el cero al textbox.
                if (parts[0].Length <= 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "0" + textBox1.Text;
                    //UPDATE: colocamos el cursor al final del texto
                    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la rápida repuesta, en realidad funciono como quería pero hay un detalle, al dar Click al punto el cursor se coloca luego del cero y no del punto, ósea al escribir 0.22 este si lo hago rápido me pone 220.

Comment: no especificaste ese problema en la pregunta, pero es fácil de arreglar, revisa mi respuesta de nuevo, la edité con ese cambio :D

Comment: okey perfecto la voy a revisar y gracias nuevamente